# Trying show the image in wide angle on rails instead of full page or thumb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 4.2.6
This is my code:

```
<%= image_tag @blog.image_url(:large), :class => "style_image" if @blog.image? %>
```

This is giving error:

```
Version large doesn't exist!
```

And this gives full blown image:

```
<%= image_tag @blog.image_url.to_s if @blog.image? %>
```

How can I make it appear just a wide enough image ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add versions if you are using carrier wave for image uploading

```
 version :large do
   process resize_to_fill: [800,800]
 end
```

then you can use

```
<%= image_tag @blog.image_url(:large), :class => "style_image" if @blog.image? %>
```